# read object file from SparkSession in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have used JavaSparkContext to write a JavaRDD as an object file:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf); //where conf is a SparkConf
JavaRDD<MyClass> something;
something.saveAsObjectFile("path");
```

I can easily load this file using:

```
JavaRDD<MyClass> loaded = sc.objectFile("path);
```

Now, in the same program, I want to load the object file and also use a SparkSession, in order to create a DataFrame from another file, so I am using:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builer()
.appName("someName")
.master("local")
.getOrCreate();
```

Is there any way to load the object file using `spark`, instead of a JavaSparkContext?

I have tried creating an instance of JavaSparkContext in the same program, but I am getting the error:

> SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243).

I know that SparkSession encapsulates the SparkContext, but how can I do what I want (in Java)? Is there any way to get a JavaSparkContext from a SparkSession? Could I use another way to write the object file using SparkSession instead of JavaSparkContext (I want to save it compressed and not as raw text)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite easy:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
```

so I am not sure if I should keep this post.

Answer (score 1):

SparkSession combines SparkContext and SqlContext so in same application if you'll try initialize SparkSession after creating SparkContext it will throw exception. So it would be better to use only SparkSession. Any case you can stop SparkContext right before initialization of SparkSession and proceed with SqlContext + SparkContext.